# Rails 3 SQLite3 Boolean false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to insert a false boolean value in a SQLite3 table but it always inserts a true value.

Here's my migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
      t.column :active, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :resources
  end
end
```

When I try to insert using rails it produces the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "active") VALUES ('test', 'f')
```

SQLite treats 'f' as true so it inserts true into my database. The query I want it to generate is:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "active") VALUES ('test', false)
```

What am I doing wrong?

rails: 3.0.7

sqlite3 gem: 1.3.3

Comment: What is your rails code that produces the SQL with 'f'?

Comment: The generated HTML looks like this: <div class="field">
    <label for="user_active">Active</label><br>
    <input name="user[active]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="user_active" name="user[active]" type="checkbox" value="1">
  </div>

Comment: The controller is a simple REST create.

Comment: Even if I do a query like: User.find(:all, :conditions => { :active => false}) the sql looks like this: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."active" = 'f'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SQLite uses [1 for true and 0 for false](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean):

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

But SQLite also has a loose type system and automatically casts things so your `'f'` is probably being interpreted as having a truthiness of "true" simply because it isn't zero.

A bit of digging indicates that you have found a bug in the Rails 3.0.7 SQLiteAdapter. In `active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb`, we find these:

```
def quoted_true
  "'t'"
end

def quoted_false
  "'f'"
end
```

So, by default, ActiveRecord assumes that the database understands `'t'` and `'f'` for boolean columns. The MySQL adaptor overrides these to work with its `tinyint` implementation of boolean columns:

```
QUOTED_TRUE, QUOTED_FALSE = '1'.freeze, '0'.freeze

#...

def quoted_true
  QUOTED_TRUE
end

def quoted_false
  QUOTED_FALSE
end
```

But the SQLite adapter does not provide its own implementations of `quoted_true` or `quoted_false` so it gets the defaults which don't work with SQLite's booleans.

The `'t'` and `'f'` booleans work in PostgreSQL so maybe everyone is using PostgreSQL with Rails 3 or they're just not noticing that their queries aren't working properly.

I'm a little surprised by this and hopefully someone can point out where I've gone wrong, you can't be the first person to use a boolean column in SQLite with Rails 3.

Try monkey patching `def quoted_true;'1';end` and `def quoted_false;'0';end` into `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteAdapter` (or temporarily hand-edit them into `active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb`) and see if you get sensible SQL.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I just can't work out why it's using 'f' instead of false or 0 because a 0 is passed in the POST.

Comment: @Mike: Have a look at my update please. I deleted my original answer, then resurrected it, and updated it based on a quick review of the ActiveRecord database adapter source code.

Comment: That's what I was thinking...I can't be the first person to come across this bug which made me think it was something to do with my environment. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else has another explanation otherwise I'll give you the credit.

Comment: @Mike: I find it hard to believe too but the code (usually) doesn't lie and your results back up what I found in the source. Try patching your `sqlite_adapter.rb` and see what happens; if the MySQL approach works for SQLite then you could send the Rails or SQLite3 developers a patch to fix it and gain fame and fortune (or maybe just a "thanks").

Comment: Turns out there's nothing wrong with the sqlite adapter. It was my database viewing software which had the bug in it. Thanks so much for your in depth answer I wish I could give you the credit.

Comment: @Mike: Rails is using `'t'` and `'f'` as boolean values in the SQLite database though, right? That would work fine as long as only Rails used the database, SQLite treats everything as a string internally so the column type in the DDL is mostly advisory. I'm just curious if I'm reading the source correctly, maybe I'll set up my own Rails/SQLite test app and see.

Comment: Correct it stores it as 't' or 'f' in the database. I guess that was the database viewer wasn't expecting that.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for checking that for me, much appreciated. The viewer you were using was probably expecting 1 or 0 for booleans (as specified in the SQLite documentation). SQLite's loose data typing means that it doesn't matter as long as the external application always uses the same values.

Comment: SQLite doesn't treat everything as strings (it's got a more complex type system than that which allows it to beat strings in many important cases, such as numbers) but it also doesn't enforce type constraints as a deliberate policy.

Comment: @Donal: Maybe "stored as strings" would be a less simplified view of reality. The real point is that the SQLite type system is (intentionally) rather loose.

Comment: This solved my boolean issue, Thanks a lot! I think indeed a bug in Rails 3??? I am using Rails 3.0.10 and this fixed my issue.

Comment: This is irritating, I lost 2 days seems because of this.

Answer (score 4):

I ran across this as well, here's how to monkey patch:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter'
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SQLite3Adapter < SQLiteAdapter
      def quoted_true; '1' end
      def quoted_false; '0' end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't get how I'm still running across this bug??

Comment: Use 't' and 'f' instead of '1' and '0'. This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with Rails 5. Do you have an updated version?

Answer (score 3):

You may find useful the following code snippet for adding compatibility with SQLite boolean columns actually working on Rails 4 (also posted at https://gist.github.com/ajoman/9391708):

```rb
# config/initializers/sqlite3_adapter_patch.rb

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SQLite3Adapter < AbstractAdapter
      QUOTED_TRUE, QUOTED_FALSE = "'t'", "'f'"

      def quoted_true
        QUOTED_TRUE
      end

      def quoted_false
        QUOTED_FALSE
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with Rails 5. Do you have an updated version?

Comment: @thisismydesign sorry I don't have an updated version since I'm not using anymore SQLite for development on Rails.

Answer (score 2):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29699) on master on 12 Jul 2017. However it is [not part of the latest stable release (5.1.4)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/quoting.rb). The most recent release where it's fixed is [v5.2.0.rc1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0.rc1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/quoting.rb).

The behaviour can be set via `Rails.application.config.active_record.sqlite3.represent_boolean_as_integer` ([default is `true`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29699#issuecomment-362298844)).

Answer (score 0):

This version works in Rails 4.1.

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter'

module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter
  QUOTED_TRUE, QUOTED_FALSE = 't'.freeze, 'f'.freeze

  def quoted_true; QUOTED_TRUE end
  def quoted_false; QUOTED_FALSE end
end
```

The constants and `.freeze` are for performance, so ruby doesn't have to regenerate those strings and garbage collect them on every call.