# PGError: ERROR: column "is_required" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to do a `db:push` to Heroku, but am getting this error:

```
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  column "is_required" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
LINE 1: ..." ("id", "question_id", "text", "response_class", "is_requir...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I'm pushing from my local database (which is sqlite) to Heroku's PostgreSQL database.

The `is_required` column is set as a boolean using `t.boolean  "is_required", :default => false`.

Not sure what to do here.

Comment: SQLite stores boolean data as integer restricted to 0 and 1. In PostgreSQL boolean is a separate data type. Explicitly casting works in PostgreSQL like this: `is_required::boolean`.

Comment: Is the error coming from the schema or the data?

Comment: It's coming from the data and the data for a boolean is stored as "0" and "1"

Comment: Looks like a bug in taps, it should be handling boolean storage format changes but apparently it isn't. Developing on top of SQLite and deploying to PostgreSQL is a really bad idea anyway, you should switch your development environment to PostgreSQL (8.3 for shared databases, 9.0 for dedicated); you will face a lot of other problems with deployment if your development and production databases aren't the same.

Comment: Also, some versions of ActiveRecord used [`'t'` and `'f'` for booleans with SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013121/rails-3-sqlite3-boolean-false/6013177#6013177) so taps might be assuming that it is working with the broken SQLite adapter from Rails 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Playing around in pgAdmin; it looks like postgres prefers the defaults in the form of `'t'` or `'f'`.  I don't have a ruby install to try it on, though.