# Boolean values with SQLite and Sequel

Tags: ruby, sqlite, boolean, sequel

Sequel supports a `boolean` type.
It stores `true` and `false` as `t` and `f` in SQLite.
If you read again, the data are converted back to `true` and `false`

SQLite itself prefers to store `true` as 1 and `false` as 0 (and some SQLite-administartion tools expect it).
If I store my boolean also as '1', Sequel also converts the value to 'true':

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite()#'test.db')
DB.create_table(:test){
  boolean :my_truth
  nvarchar :descr, :size => 10
}
DB[:test].insert(1, '1')
p DB[:test].filter(:descr => '1').first #-> {:my_truth=>true, :descr=>"1"}
```

But if I select for `true`, no value is found:

```
DB[:test].filter(:my_truth => true).each{|ds|
  puts "\t%s" % ds[:descr]
}
```

The values `true` and `"t"` are found:

```
DB[:test].insert(true, 'true')
DB[:test].insert('t', '"t"')
DB[:test].filter(:my_truth => true).each{|ds|
  puts "\t%s" % ds[:descr]    #true and 't'
}
```

There is a similar situation for false-values like `0`... (see example code after the question)

So **my question**:
How can i make `DB[:test].filter(:my_truth => true)` to detect `1`-values and 
`DB[:test].filter(:my_truth => false)` to detect `0`-values?

I'm not looking for something like `DB[:test].filter(:my_truth => [true,1])`

Similar question for Activerecord
[Rails 3 SQLite3 Boolean false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013121/rails-3-sqlite3-boolean-false)

I use Sequel 3.33.0

---

Example code:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite()#'test.db')
DB.create_table(:test){
  boolean :my_truth
  nvarchar :descr, :size => 10
  fixnum :line  #code line, where data is inserted
}

#All true:
DB[:test].insert(true, 'true', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('true', '"true"', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert(1, 'one', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('t', 't', __LINE__)

#All false:
DB[:test].insert(false,'false', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('false','"false"', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert(0,'zero', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('f', 'f', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('F', 'F', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert(nil, 'nil', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('n', 'n', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('N', 'N', __LINE__)

#Also true
DB[:test].insert('x', 'x', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert(' ', 'space', __LINE__)
DB[:test].insert('', 'empty', __LINE__)

puts "All true values:"
DB[:test].filter(:my_truth => true).each{|ds|
  puts "\t%s (line %i)" % [ds[:descr],  ds[:line] ]
}

puts "All false values:"
DB[:test].filter(:my_truth => false).each{|ds|
  puts "\t%s (line %i)" % [ds[:descr],  ds[:line] ]
}

puts "Data:"
DB[:test].each{|ds|
  puts "\t%-5s is <%s> (line %i)" % [ ds[:descr], ds[:my_truth].inspect, ds[:line] ]
}
```

Result:

```
All true values:
  true (line 10)
  t (line 13)
All false values:
  false (line 16)
  f (line 19)
Data:
  true  is <true> (line 10)
  "true" is <true> (line 11)
  one   is <true> (line 12)
  t     is <true> (line 13)
  false is <false> (line 16)
  "false" is <false> (line 17)
  zero  is <false> (line 18)
  f     is <false> (line 19)
  F     is <false> (line 20)
  nil   is <nil> (line 21)
  n     is <false> (line 22)
  N     is <false> (line 23)
  x     is <true> (line 26)
  space is <true> (line 27)
  empty is <true> (line 28)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the integer_booleans setting to use 1/0 as true/false, instead of 't'/'f', see http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/SQLite/DatabaseMethods.html.  Here's an example:

```
DB = Sequel.sqlite(:integer_booleans=>true)
```

Comment: Great! I just tested on my 2nc PC without success, but there I had sequel 3.28. After upgrading it works. Thanks!