# Taking the average of a boolean column in both postgres and sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I've got a lot of ActiveRecord queries that find a percentage using the average of an expression, for example:

```
def self.undergraduate_degree_percentage
  self.average("undergrad_college_name != ''")
end
```

These were built for sqlite3 (the development database) but break down in postgres (the production database) because pg handles booleans differently.  The error generated is something like `ERROR:  function avg(boolean) does not exist at character 8`.  Is there an elegant way to make this type of query work for both sqlite3 and PG?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem just an advice: Try using the same database in development that you are using in production. If you're on a Mac, Postgres is quite easy to use with [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) or installed with Homebrew. It's one of the best headache avoiding moves I ever made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean values in databases are difficult to work with portably:

1. MySQL and SQLite use C-style booleans natively.
2. The ActiveRecord driver for SQLite sometimes mistakenly [uses `'t'` and `'f'` strings for booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013177/479863). This might be fixed in newer versions.
3. PostgreSQL has a native boolean type.
4. Other databases do other things.
5. Sometimes there are automatic casts to numeric values and sometimes there aren't.
6. ?
7. [Profit.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underpants_gnomes)

If you want to do this portably, then you should convert the booleans by hand. In your case, you are lucky to have an expression that yields a native boolean value so you don't have to worry about AR's SQLite brain damage. A simple CASE should make things work the same everywhere:

```
self.average(%q{
  case
    when undergrad_college_name != '' then 1.0
    else 0.0
  end
})
```

That will give you a floating point result (probably a Float or BigDecimal) and then you can decide how you want deal with it from there.