# How to handle booleans in a Rails app with both SQLite and PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I have a ruby on rails application where I am using SQLite for development and testing, and I am using PostgreSQL in production. How can I write queries that handle booleans in my models that can handle both cases? SQLite handles booleans by using `0` and `1` , and PostgreSQL uses `t` and `f`, which is causing my problems.

Comment: consider using the same database for both development and production, there is no reason not to really

Comment: Has ActiveRecord fixed its [boolean brain damage with SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6013177/479863)? SQLite certainly thinks that booleans are C-style numbers but ActiveRecord hasn't always done so with SQLite. Anyway, stop smashing your own head with a brick and start developing on top of PostgreSQL if that's what you're deploying on, building a non-trivial database-portable application is very difficult and no ORM will protect you from the subtle differences.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `true`/`false`. ActiveRecord will handle the rest.

So for example: `Post.where(published: true)`