# sqlite boolean 't' and 'f' with rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I use mysql on production and sqlite3 on my development.

When querying my database on development e.g.

```
@follow_ups = FollowUp.where(is_complete: false)
```

I get the sql below in my console

```
SELECT "follow_ups".* FROM "follow_ups"  WHERE "follow_ups"."is_complete" = 'f'
```

sqlite evaluates 'f' as a truthy value so no follow_ups.is_complete = false are returned. In the database they are stored as true/false. From my investigations I found.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10720
[Rails 3 SQLite3 Boolean false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013121/rails-3-sqlite3-boolean-false)

What should I do to get my boolean filters working? I would have thought this would be happening to more people.

See schema below

```
  create_table "follow_ups", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "contact_id"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.datetime "due_date"
    t.string   "comment"
    t.boolean  "is_complete",        default: false
    t.integer  "created_by_user_id"
    t.integer  "updated_by_user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

See data and insertions below - done via rails console. As request in comments.

```
[30] pry(main)> FollowUp.create(contact_id: 1, due_date: Time.now, is_complete: true)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "follow_ups" ("contact_id", "created_at", "due_date", "is_complete", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["contact_id", 1], ["created_at", "2014-04-22 19:17:01.854402"], ["due_date", "2014-04-22 19:17:01.853540"], ["is_complete", "t"], ["updated_at", "2014-04-22 19:17:01.854402"]]
   (1.7ms)  commit transaction
#<FollowUp:0x0000010699c5a8> {
                    :id => 23,
            :contact_id => 1,
              :owner_id => nil,
              :due_date => Tue, 22 Apr 2014 19:17:01 UTC +00:00,
               :comment => nil,
           :is_complete => true,
    :created_by_user_id => nil,
    :updated_by_user_id => nil,
            :created_at => Tue, 22 Apr 2014 19:17:01 UTC +00:00,
            :updated_at => Tue, 22 Apr 2014 19:17:01 UTC +00:00
}
[31] pry(main)> FollowUp.where(is_complete: true)
  FollowUp Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "follow_ups".* FROM "follow_ups"  WHERE "follow_ups"."is_complete" = 't'
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<FollowUp id: 16, contact_id: 1, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-23 00:00:00", comment: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin...", is_complete: true, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-17 09:57:00", updated_at: "2014-04-22 14:37:36">, #<FollowUp id: 23, contact_id: 1, owner_id: nil, due_date: "2014-04-22 19:17:01", comment: nil, is_complete: true, created_by_user_id: nil, updated_by_user_id: nil, created_at: "2014-04-22 19:17:01", updated_at: "2014-04-22 19:17:01">]>
[32] pry(main)> FollowUp.where(is_complete: false)
  FollowUp Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "follow_ups".* FROM "follow_ups"  WHERE "follow_ups"."is_complete" = 'f'
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
[33] pry(main)> FollowUp.all
  FollowUp Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "follow_ups".* FROM "follow_ups"
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<FollowUp id: 16, contact_id: 1, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-23 00:00:00", comment: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin...", is_complete: true, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-17 09:57:00", updated_at: "2014-04-22 14:37:36">, #<FollowUp id: 17, contact_id: 1, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-24 00:00:00", comment: "This ia  long comment", is_complete: false, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-17 10:04:13", updated_at: "2014-04-17 10:04:13">, #<FollowUp id: 18, contact_id: 1, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-24 00:00:00", comment: "This is a comment\r\n", is_complete: false, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-17 10:24:05", updated_at: "2014-04-17 10:24:05">, #<FollowUp id: 19, contact_id: 1, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-23 00:00:00", comment: "test", is_complete: false, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-22 13:37:40", updated_at: "2014-04-22 13:37:40">, #<FollowUp id: 20, contact_id: 1, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-23 00:00:00", comment: "test", is_complete: false, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-22 13:37:41", updated_at: "2014-04-22 13:37:41">, #<FollowUp id: 21, contact_id: 1, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-24 00:00:00", comment: "test", is_complete: false, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-22 13:39:20", updated_at: "2014-04-22 13:39:20">, #<FollowUp id: 22, contact_id: 2, owner_id: 1, due_date: "2014-04-30 00:00:00", comment: "test", is_complete: false, created_by_user_id: 1, updated_by_user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-22 13:53:37", updated_at: "2014-04-22 13:53:37">, #<FollowUp id: 23, contact_id: 1, owner_id: nil, due_date: "2014-04-22 19:17:01", comment: nil, is_complete: true, created_by_user_id: nil, updated_by_user_id: nil, created_at: "2014-04-22 19:17:01", updated_at: "2014-04-22 19:17:01">]>
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of `follow_ups` table?

Comment: `In the database they are stored as true/false`? As per as I know with sqlite boolean fields are stored with `t` or `f` values. Can you share the output of running `SELECT * FROM follow_ups LIMIT 5;"` in `rails dbconsole`

Comment: Does SQLite return your data when you call `FollowUp.where(is_complete: true)`?

Comment: Yes ... which i don't understand either ...

Comment: Rails 5.2 has now a config option to specify this: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter.represent_boolean_as_integer`

Answer (score 5):

In sqlite3, boolean value is not supported. So rails use char 't' and 'f' to represent boolean value true and false. while in other database like mysql, postgresql, the real boolean value true and false is used.

However, this difference is transparent to rails Model. you can just use

```
FollowUp.where(is_compete: true)
```

to filter completed followups and

```
FollowUp.where(is_compete: false)
```

to get incomplete followups

Comment: Minor correction: MySQL does not have a native ("real") boolean data type; it maps it to TINYINT.

Comment: Not at all transparent unfortunately. Try `if follow_up.is_compete` for a false value..

Answer (score 1):

Using sqlite3 in Rails 4.2.5, I find that a boolean field returns ruby true or false when queried from Rails console. However, when queried inside a controller method, it returns a "t" or "f" string. Very weird. So I added a model method:

```
def fixt?
    return self[:fixt] == "t"
end
```

Schema:

```
 t.boolean  "fixt",                  default: false
```